# Deleting QStandardItems from QStandardItemModel

Tags: qt, delete-row, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I am trying to delete `QStandardItems` from `QStandrditemModel` using `QPersistentIndex`. Items are successfully deleted, but when iterate through the model the deleted rows appear without any data.

I am using the following code to delete the items:

```
QList<QPersistentModelIndex> selectedIndexes;

foreach (const QModelIndex &modelIndex, this->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
{
    selectedIndexes << modelIndex;
}

foreach (const QPersistentModelIndex &index, selectedIndexes)
{
    QPersistentModelIndex parentIndex = index.parent();   
    model->removeRow(index.row(),parentIndex); 
}

// In another function
foreach (const QModelIndex &index, this->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
{ // do soemthing and the items appear without any data as shown
  // in the image below
}
```

[The Screenshot](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=848282qterror.png)

Comment: Does `model` == `this`?

Comment: My fail... Does your code executed in one method? Are there real reasons to use `QPersistentModelIndex` instead of `QModelIndex`? What you are doing in third loop?

Comment: I used QPersistentModelIndex, because when i try to delete the multiple items, QModelIndex changes when first item is deleted. that's why i used QPersistentModel Index.

The third loop is not in the same function, It is in another function. In this loop, i again select the indexes ad perform operations e.g. Editing the selected items, then the strange behaviour is shown as shown in screenshot.

Comment: I did not actually found a solution. but i found another strange behaviour, when i try to set  the interface with some UI components, Then for one combobox, if i changes its index or comment(//) this line. Then i do not get the empty items in the tree when the third loop is executed.

I know it does not make sense at all. But this is how it works. I do not know why.

Comment: Why you are not deleting `QStandardItem`? Build list of items `QList<QStandardItem *>` and call `qDeleteAll`.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'm experiencing the same issue with blank rows left in the model. I'm actually getting the list of items and using qDeleteAll and ending up with exactly the effect described. I'm using Qt 5.6, and don't have the ability to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is that deleting the items doesn't seem to properly clean up the model. I experimented with various workarounds, and the one that worked is this:

```
    QList <QStandardItem *> items = ...some list of items to remove...

    for (int i = 0; i < items.count (); i++)
    {
        QStandardItem *parent = items[i]->parent ();

        if (parent)
        {
            QList <QStandardItem *> row_items = parent->takeRow (items[i]->row ());
            qDeleteAll (row_items);
        }
    }
```

Using "takeChild" didn't work, nor did any other mechanism I tried. Without digging through the Qt code, what seems to be happening is that deleting a single item isn't removing the row containing that item even when it's the only item in the row.

In my case, I only ever have one item per row, so the above code is safe, but if there's any possibility that the "items" list contains two or more items on the same row, then the above code would be unstable since the act of removing the first item that's encountered in the list would be deleting another item as well.